# Javascript innerHTML ignores Text Format

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following value in table cell with bold & colour formatting

> cell id="total"; value="**HI**"

But when i change the value of the cell as below, it ignores text formatting

```
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Hello"
```

and resulting in

```
Hello (with out bold and color)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are replacing the existing content with just "Hello" -- the styling of the previous content was due to properties of the content itself, and that doesn't stick around because that content is wiped out.

If you want styling for your new content you need to provide it manually, for example

```
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "<strong>Hello</strong>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution would be to apply your styles through a stylesheet, as follows:

```css
#total {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FF0000; /* Replace this with the right color */
}
```

Now,

```
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Hello";
```

should allow the cell to keep its styles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the best approach would probably be to use CSS styles.